# Checkout menu without images

Tags: css

What's the best practice to create a checkout (tracking) menu like below in CSS.

[image]

How to create this menu without images? e.g. With CSS triangles?

Comment: The best practice is to do it in images.

Comment: you could make it a Background with all 4 going vertical down and just change the Bg-position. Then you have one image only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS triangles, as described on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). Then, apply [CSS-gradient](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) to your background. Oh, and there is a slight `border-radius` needs to be applied on the first (and, probably, last) element.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, you cannot apply CSS-gradients to the triangular part, since its background is actually the color of the border.

And, well, the gradients don't work well across all browsers, so you will have to fallback to a plain image for older versions thereof.

**UPDATE:**
An, of course, as @BoltClock suggests you could use a single sprite image, accompanied by `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements.

*Sample sprite image:*

[image: Sample sprite]